# RCTWebSocketModule.connect was called with 4 arguments, but expects 2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

My application ran into a problem, When I start my application in Xcode it gives me this error:

> RCTWebSocketModule.connect was called with 4 arguments, but expects 2

Previously it was working really fine, but when I started my system again and try to build it, it displayed me this error.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall your packages. Worked for me and for him: [RCTWebSocketModule.connect was called with 2 argum...](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6225)

Comment: Attempted this and am still seeing the error. Anyone else having the same problem?

Comment: Which RN version are you on? And are you using Linking or LinkingIOS?

Comment: I also did a Product > Clean from Xcode after reinstalling my packages.

Answer (score 1):

I was seeing this error when integrate  RN with existing apps. Because my native code depend RN version 0.19, but npm start server depend on RN 0.22 .

0.19: 2 arguments
`RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(connect:(NSURL *)URL socketID:(nonnull NSNumber *)socketID)`

0.22: 4 arguments
`RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(connect:(NSURL *)URL protocols:(NSArray *)protocols headers:(NSDictionary *)headers socketID:(nonnull NSNumber *)socketID)`

Answer (score 0):

Some steps that might work:

1. If on iOS, start the app again by pressing the play button.
2. Close the server, and do `react-native run-ios` again
3. `rm -rf node_modules/` and `npm install`